# Spring Cloud Contract - array of strings as query parameter

Tags: spring, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-contract

I'm looking for a way to generate contract for query parameter which is an array, ie(based on open-api):

```
Arrays can be serialized as:

form – /products?color=blue,green,red or /products?color=blue&color=green, depending on the explode keyword
spaceDelimited (same as collectionFormat: ssv in OpenAPI 2.0) – /products?color=blue%20green%20red
pipeDelimited (same as collectionFormat: pipes in OpenAPI 2.0) – /products?color=blue|green|red
```

In current solution I simply accept everything:

```
Contract.make {
    request {
        method 'GET'
        urlPath ('/products'){
            queryParameters {
              parameter 'color': value(any())
            }
        }
        headers {
            header 'corrid': $(anyNonBlankString())
        }
    }
    response {

    }
}
```

In docs I cannot found this example: https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-contract/2.0.x/multi/multi__contract_dsl.html#_request

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regex for that. Although I would not recommended using Spring Cloud Contract to test the values of your API, it is intended to test the structure.

It should be possible like this:

```
email: $(consumer(optional(regex(email()))), producer('abc@abc.com')),
```

You can take a look at the build in options to provide your own.
More info:
https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-contract/reference/html/project-features.html#contract-dsl-regex